# Postgresql - JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, elasticsearch

I have a table with data. I exported this to JSON. It looks something like this:

```
{"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T08:57:48.646Z","ip":"0.0.0.0","extension":"php","response":"404","geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":33.48288111,"lon":-90.98561389},"src":"MD","dest":"ID","srcdest":"MD:ID"},"@tags":["success","info"]}
```

There are thousands of these lines. However, I would like to insert an incremental id that looks like this: {"index":{"_id":"1"}} before each line of the JSON. Output should look something like this:

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}} 
{"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T08:57:48.646Z","ip":"0.0.0.0","extension":"php","response":"404","geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":33.48288111,"lon":-90.98561389},"src":"MD","dest":"ID","srcdest":"MD:ID"},"@tags":["success","info"]}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}} 
{"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T08:57:48.646Z","ip":"0.0.0.0","extension":"php","response":"404","geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":33.48288111,"lon":-90.98561389},"src":"MD","dest":"ID","srcdest":"MD:ID"},"@tags":["success","info"]}
```

Any ideas how I can do that in JSON OR if I can export it that way in postgres?

Comment: Do you want to change the exported (text) file, or do you want to change the data in the SQL statement you use for exporting?

Comment: whichever way. I just need a json output with the format stated. Basically, I have it in postgresql and exported to json. And that's what I got. I just need to add index to each line item as seen on my original post. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: How do you currently export the data to JSON? You should add the table definition and your current query if you want a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really give you a better answer without any additional information, as I understand you have this data normalized in a table, so not `JSON` in `JSON|JSONB` column.

If this is the case, you obviously know how to get it out. Your problem it seems to be boils down to adding a column to a table, in your case named `index` (though I would advise using another name, as `index` is a reserved word), maybe idx would be work.

Anyway without knowing more (number of records for example, or other constraints you have to work with), I would suggest creating a new table with a serial column and just reinserting your values, thus producing the desired result, and solving the problem for the foreseeable future, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table WITH NO DATA;
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD COLUMN idx SERIAL;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

This will produce a table `new_table` with all the values from table `old_table` and a new column `idx` which contains the ids you are after (or look like you are after :) ).

Finally drop `old_table`:

```
DROP TABLE old_table;
```

And update any scripts that depend on the old table.

Hope this gets you on the right track...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just adding a new id serial table and exporting to JSON will only export it as another column. Currently there are about 1M entries in the access log. I imported this into postgresql and have it in tables already. I also exported to JSON which is what I have in the description above. However, I need to add index & _id for each entry / row. I'm really a newbie here and I apologize if I'm lacking certain information. :) Self studying and this place has been great so far!

Comment: It really is just adding the index & _id before each row. I'm trying to get this imported into elastic and this is all that's left for me to do. I did sample JSON imports and it is working in elastic. If you do know an easier way, please let me know. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us how your source looks like and how you export the data, but if you export the result of a SQL query you can simply add `row_number()` to the result:

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
  select row_number() over () as id, 
         * -- all the other columns
  from the_table
) t
```

This will assign the IDs in no particular order. If you need that, add an `order by` to the window function, e.g. `row_number() over (order by "timestamp")`

Comment: This is somewhat close to what I need. The result is: {"id":1,"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T08:57:48.646Z","ip":"0.0.0.0","extension":"php","response":"404","geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":33.48288111,"lon":-90.98561389},"src":"MD","dest":"ID","srcdest":"MD:ID"},"@tags":["success","info"]}
However, I need to export it with the format mentioned above. I'm trying to play around with it. Thank you very much for your response.